# Linker Error When Changing Visual Studio Output to System32

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-10

For a research, I'm developing a `Proxy DLL` for `nvcuda.dll` (NVIDIA CUDA runtime) which resides in `System32`. To ease up debugging I change linker output to `System32`, however, I receive

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll'
```

Here are the solutions I have tried:

1. Disabled the `UAC`.
2. Took ownership of `System32` folder.
3. Ran the program `as admin`.

There are no white-spaces in the path to the file and no other program uses the DLL (it can be removed and renamed manually). The linker works fine for any other location, am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
An interesting observation is that I am able to build the same solution using `msbuild` as follows:

```
msbuild nvcuda.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: In order for Visual Studio (and subsequently the spawned link.exe process) to copy files under C:\Windows, you'll need to run the VS IDE as Administrator. If you are an admin on the machine in question, and you run the IDE "as Administrator, that should work. At least it did on my Win10 1909 box. Now if it's in use by another process all bets are off. You might want to monitor the file io operations with something like SysInternals ProcMon utility to see if something is locking the file.

Comment: @EdDore Sure, I am the admin and I have also ran the VS `as Administrator`. In order to make sure that it is not in use by other processes, I changed the output name to `nvcuda1.dll` which does not exist. However, the problem remained.

Comment: Whether you are mixing 32 and 64 bit? You may have installed a 32-bit version of the library, but you are building for 64-bits, or vice-versa.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT No, that's not the case.